# Javascript Code To Refresh This Kind Of Captcha

Tags: javascript, html

Guys i am looking for refreshing Captcha without refresh the page , and there is no refresh button ... is there anyway i can make this work out ?

this is the captcha part in the HTML document , i could'nt find the class section .

```
     <img class="captcha" border="0" src="https://www.gametwist.com/web/Captcha-Image/? 
     bc=000000&fc=188eae&h=58&w=258&fill=ffffff" alt="captcha image">
```

Comment: can you recreate this in a fiddle?

Comment: @jmore009 what exactly ? it's a website code i used ...  for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way would be adding some random or timestamp parameter so that browser had to make new request, downloading new image. For example:

```
document.querySelector('.captcha').src += '&_=' + Date.now();
```

This code will append new GET parameter to query string similar to `&_=1420922523150`.

Comment: Okay, inject it, what is that problem? Open console and execute this snippet.

Comment: the problem is it's working fine but the captcha doesn't change letters or numbers it changes dirctions or letters colors .. so instead of bold letters , schlagt letters and so

Comment: is there anything i can do ?

Comment: Can you provide a link to website?

Comment: no need i figured it out , the website is changing the captcha when the successful form sabmission is done by a user ..